# Spring data jpa update entity

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have setup two simple entityes (City, Person) extending CRUDRepository. Person  has a `@ManyToOne` resource link to City. Both have value "id" as primary key. Saving and deleting functions work well. I have also created a `@RepositoryRestController` to catch all POST request incoming to my entityes repository endpoint *(localhost:8080/api/person)*. My post request catch function looks like this:

```
  private final PersonRepository personRepository;

  public PersonRepositoryRestController(PersonRepository personRepository) {
     this.personRepository = personRepository;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/persons")
  public @ResponseBody
  Person post(@RequestBody Resource<Person> personResource) {
    Person person = personResource.getContent();
    personRepository.save(person);
    return person;
  }
```

If I were to post a new person, then everything works as expected. But if I change the value City in Person and POST it, then the method creates a new entity instead of updating existing one. I think, its because it doesn't find the existing entity for some reason. If I debug it, the "id" field is null there, even tho in my post log I can see, that the "id" value exists.

**UPDATE**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class City extends implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private long id;
      private String name;
      private String location;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private long id;
      private name;
      @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
      private City city;
}
```

**UPDATE II**
I haven't created a RepositoryRestController for my City entity, because there is no need. POST and GET methods work fine there. Updating the entity also works there.

POST/PUT method parameters from log:

```
parameters {
    name:"Tim"
    id:1
    city:"http://localhost:8080/api/city/3"
    links:{} 3 keys {
        self:{} 1 key
        href:"http://localhost:8080/api/persons/1"
        person:{} 2 keys
        href:"http://localhost:8080/api/persons/1{?projection}"
        templated:true
        city:{} 1 key
        href:"http://localhost:8080/api/persons/1/city"
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you use `PUT` instead of `POST`?

Comment: It's still the same. Maybe the problem lies in my POST/PUT parameters. If I add a new Person, the the city parameter is url as string to city reference. So I use the same logic here.

Comment: I I dont post it as url, then city is null and all other values are there. If I post city as url, then the correct city is there but it is null.

Comment: Please update you post with all details (Client access, log data, format...). Even in your Rest controller there is nothing about an entity save / update.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. POST is for creating new resources, so do use PUT
2. please add the complete curl statement you are using for the PUT, the comments are really confusing because they seem to describe a different problem than your question.

Comment: I'm using PUT. I do not know the curl statement, I'm using axios on frontend for handlig there kind of things.